# Storing an array in ngStorage

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ng-storage

I wish to store an array using ngStorage for persistent data needs. Here is my code :

```
.factory("items", function () {
    var items = {};
    items.data = [];
    return items; 
 })

.controller('ItemsController', function($scope,items) {
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.addItem = function (id,item,size,price,quantity) {
        items.data.push({id,item,size,price,quantity});
   }
 })
```

I need to store the items array in ngStorage

Comment: Please read the documentation https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: have you tried using ngStorage yet? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('ItemsController', function ($scope, items, $localStorage) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.addItem = function (id, item, size, price, quantity) {
    items.data.push({id, item, size, price, quantity});
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));  
  }
});
```